# TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, ajv

I have this class where I try to instantiate [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) with the new keyword and I get this error:

> TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor

Code:

```
import * as Ajv from "ajv";

    export class ValidateJsonService {
        validateJson(json, schema) {
            console.log(Ajv);
            let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
            if (!ajv.validate(schema, json)) {
                throw new Error("JSON does not conform to schema: " + ajv.errorsText())
            }
        }
    }
```

The console log:

[image]

This code used to be working and it is how Ajv is used. From the Ajv docs:

> The fastest validation call:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv(); // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var valid = validate(data);
if (!valid) console.log(validate.errors);
```

How come I'm getting this error?

See the bottom of this for how I import the Ajv library - systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'lib/js/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            app: 'app', 
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'angular2-google-maps/core': 'npm:angular2-google-maps/core/core.umd.js',
            'ajv': 'npm:ajv/dist/ajv.min.js',
            'primeng': 'npm:primeng'
```

Comment: import Ajv from 'ajv'

Comment: @esp I went with this in the end.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Do you know where should i change it ``let ajv = new Ajv.default({ allErrors: true });```I mean is it under node_modules  > ajv > lib ?

Comment: @soccerway no, not in node_modules. In your own code where you want to use Ajv. It will replace this line in my question: `let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });` 
 and `var ajv = new Ajv(); // options can be passed, e.g. {allErrors: true}`. It is just creating a new instance of Ajv to then use.

Comment: Sorry I am not using AJV in my code...i haven't used that one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I saw that Ajv has a default function so I changed my code to this:

```
let ajv = new Ajv.default({ allErrors: true });
```

Not 100% sure what is going on there but it works.

Comment: for me `let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });` worked today.

Comment: As per the documentation (https://ajv.js.org/guide/getting-started.html#basic-data-validation) you could also have:
const Ajv = require('ajv').default;
const ajv = new Ajv();

Answer (score 2):

Old question and old answer, but since I think the accepted answer isn't ideal and also leaves unanswered questions, I'm still adding my $.02:

What's causing this is that `ajv` uses `export default` or `export =`  syntax, and you're using `import * as` which imports an object with all exported members from the `ajv` module, where the default export is a property called `default`.

The most reasonable way to import the default constructor function is to use:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv(...);
```

rather than

```
import * as Ajv from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv.default(...); // Ajv is an object containing _all_ exports from the ajv module
```

If you absolutely feel that you must use `import *`, then this would at least be cleaner, so that `Ajv` rather than `Ajv.default` is the constructor function:

```
import * as AjvModule from 'ajv';
const {default: Ajv} = AjvModule;
```

If using `require` rather than `import` to access exported members from a module that uses `export default`, it will behave like `import * as Ajv`, i.e., you will get an object with a `default` property in it.

So the following are equivalent:

```
// Pre-ES6 require
const Ajv = require('ajv').default;
const ajv = new Ajv(...);

// Import default
import Ajv from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv(...);

// Import entire module and use default property
import * as Ajv from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv.default(...); // just ugly!

// Import entire module as AjvModule and assign constructor function to Ajv
import * as AjvModule from 'ajv';
const {default: Ajv} = AjvModule;
const ajv = new Ajv(...);
```

If you do need to import the default export *and* additional exported members, you can do that without resorting to `import * as` :

```
import Ajv, {EnumParams} from 'ajv';
const ajv = new Ajv(...);
```

Personally I think the accepted answer is somewhat flawed because if you're only interested in importing the ajv constructor function, it makes sense to assign *it*  to the `Ajv` variable rather than the *object that contains* the constructor function as a property called `default` - and then create classes with `new Ajv.default` syntax - that just looks strange.

Comment: ONLY the accepted answer works for me in Nodejs, but not with webpack. In webpack, ONLY your answer works, `import Ajv from 'ajv'`, using ajv `7.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I was previously using AJV on a project that was targeting CommonJS with this tsconfig and corresponding typescript:

```json
{
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
}
```

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';

const ajv = new Ajv.default();
```

But after updating our project I was not able to use the above. I started getting an error that *`Ajv.default is not a constructor`*. Trying to use `new Ajv()` did not work either... with a similar typescript-only error. The solution was to do this sillyness (NOTE: the intellisense still works!):

```json
{
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
}
```

```
import AjvDefault from 'avj';

const Ajv = AjvDefault as unknown as typeof AjvDefault.default;
const ajv = new Ajv();
```

I really hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -4):

Simply you don't have to do anything,
just install ajv package
"npm install ajv"
it will resolve avj is not a constructor issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32854797)