# AJV and ajv-formats latest must be broken in React

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I've been using AJV for validation, for a few months now. Was on v6.x for a while and now need to upgrade to get formatting and custom error messages to work. Unfortunately, it seems horribly broken. I can't find any help in bug reports and other chatter out there.

Packages:

```
"ajv": "^8.8.2",
"ajv-errors": "^3.0.0",
"ajv-formats": "^2.1.1",
```

To be clear, I can get this to work in Express APIs just fine, declared like so:

```
const Ajv = require("ajv");
const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, strict: false });
const ajvFormats = require("ajv-formats")(ajv);
const ajvErrors = require("ajv-errors")(ajv);
```

However, I'm also using it in React projects and that's where it barfs. Declared like so:

```
import Ajv from "ajv";
import AjvFormats from "ajv-formats";
import AjvErrors from "ajv-errors";
const ajv = new Ajv({ 
    allErrors: true, 
    strict: false, 
    strictTypes: false,
    code: { optimize: false } 
});
AjvErrors(ajv);
AjvFormats(ajv);
```

No matter the options used in the Ajv constructor, it yields the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allErrors')
ajvErrors
src/index.ts:385
Module.<anonymous>
src/mod/validator.js:10
   7 |     strictTypes: false,
   8 |     code: { optimize: false } 
   9 | });
> 10 | AjvErrors(ajv);
  11 | AjvFormats(ajv);
```

If I comment out the AjvErrors(ajv) line to see if formats will work, I get a separate and entirely different error for AjvFormats(ajv):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code')
addFormats
src/index.ts:55
  52 |     if (items) {
  53 |         errors.items = {};
  54 |         for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
> 55 |             errors.items[i] = [];
     | ^  56 |     }
  57 |     return errors;
  58 | }
View compiled
formatsPlugin
src/index.ts:42
  39 |     const schMessage = typeof sch == "string" ? sch : sch._;
  40 |     if (schMessage)
  41 |         processAllErrors(schMessage);
> 42 |     if (!options.keepErrors)
     | ^  43 |         removeUsedErrors();
  44 | });
  45 | function childErrorsConfig({ properties, items }) {
View compiled
Module.<anonymous>
src/mod/validator.js:11
   8 |     code: { optimize: false } 
   9 | });
  10 | // AjvErrors(ajv);
> 11 | AjvFormats(ajv);
  12 | 
  13 | const initValidationCache = async () => {
  14 |     let { entityType, schema } = window;
```

Am I SOL? Are these projects dead? There's very little activity in the bug reports I'm seeing out there. I've already invested a ton of time and wrote a lot of code around this lib, as my validation library, because it's downloaded tens-of-millions of times per month. Seemed safe! Not super encouraging. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer, if no one else has anything, is finding the package version sweet spot. Sure would be nice to not waste hours trying to piece this together:

```
npm install ajv@7.2.3 ajv-errors@2.0.1 ajv-formats@2.1.1 --save
```

What's hilarious about this is; it works in React just fine like so:

```
import Ajv from "ajv";
import AjvFormats from "ajv-formats";
import AjvErrors from "ajv-errors";
const ajv = new Ajv({ 
    allErrors: true, 
    strict: false
});
AjvFormats(ajv);
AjvErrors(ajv);
```

But these *exact same package versions* in my Express API now bombs:

```
const Ajv = require("ajv");
const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, strict: false }); //this fails!
const AjvFormats = require("ajv-formats");
const AjvErrors = require("ajv-errors");
AjvFormats(ajv);
AjvErrors(ajv);
```

...with this error..which seems absurd.

> Ajv is not a constructor

I'm at a loss, really. I'm ready to swing back to Joi because I never had a problem with several years of use.

UPDATE:

This resolves the problem with constructor error above:
[TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103343/typeerror-ajv-is-not-a-constructor)

AJV and related appear to be moving targets. I'm setting this version in stone and never upgrading!