# Ionic/angular serve ajv-errors error of Cannot read property 'allErrors' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've got an ionic project I'm working on and I'm getting the console error of

```
[ng] NOT SUPPORTED: option jsonPointers. Deprecated jsPropertySyntax can be used instead.
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'allErrors' of undefined
[ng] See "/private/var/folders/3f/chjh7cx96mv1zkr690ytb0yr0000gn/T/ng-RX4zto/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The angular-errors.log file looks like this

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'allErrors' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/skel/web/scratk/gettwoit-frontend/node_modules/ajv-errors/index.js:4:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/skel/web/scratk/gettwoit-frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/skel/web/scratk/gettwoit-frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/src/index.js:7:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after posting this question i changed how I was looking at the problem.

I cam across this question/answer [AJV and ajv-formats latest must be broken in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455362/ajv-and-ajv-formats-latest-must-be-broken-in-react)

I found the answer from @Tsar Bomba about installing

```js
npm install ajv@7.2.3 ajv-errors@2.0.1 ajv-formats@2.1.1 --save
```

Worked for me and I was able to serve my project again